# Can I edit an unsent / scheduled Parse Push Notifications from the web console?

Tags: push-notification, parse-platform

Can I edit a unsent and Scheduled Parse Push Notifications from the web console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can delete scheduled-but-unsent Push Notifications, but you can't edit them. You could always delete and recreate it though. It's like editing, but more work.